# Create record from modal edit form

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development, mvc, modal

Is there a standard Joomla mechanism / development pattern for creating a modal edit form to create an item from within another item?

I've used [this tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_modal_form_field) to create a modal list view, where you can select an item from a list of items, but the workflow I'm looking for is:

1. Open the 'edit' view of an existing record (for example, 'Personnel')
2. Click a button within this view to open the 'edit' view of another record type (for example, 'Qualification') in a modal window
3. In this modal, load the 'Qualification' form / view and allow the user to enter all relevant details, then click 'Save' - closing the modal
4. Return the pertinent details of the newly created 'Qualification' record and inject them into the original 'Personnel' view using jQuery or similar, or reload the original 'Personnel' view forcing the data to update

Is the tutorial linked to above the best starting point, then just working out the kinks regarding the saved data, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, to achieve your goal, open another view edit layout in a modal is the correct way. you can also use this code to use modal popup in joomla. Here is the URL: http://www.escope.cz/en/blog/84-how-to-use-modal-box-in-joomla